# Deploy Serverless (Faas) locally instead of using Cloud Providers

Tags: containers, microservices, serverless

Is local deploy Serverless architecture a good idea to optimize system performance (event driven) and reduce server operational cost instead of using Cloud Provider like AWS?

Comment: By locally you mean on your own servers?

Comment: Yes Constantin.

Answer (score 1):

The idea with Serverless is that you reduce server operational costs by **not having servers**.

If you provide your own servers then Serverless is pointless, you have the worst of both worlds.

Comment: Thank you. But with functions invoked by event instead of constant on but idle, isn't that going to optimism local server performance?

Comment: @Joshy invokation triggered by events  does optimize resource utilization but you still have to pay for buying the server, the electrical bill and for the ops engineer that keeps it running.